# Fading textures in spritekit?

Tags: ios, textures, sprite-kit, fade

It's not critically important to what I am doing, but I am curious as to if it is possible.

I have a button with a normal state and a clicked state. I figure it would look nice if I could have the texture fade between the two when clicked (more specifically, fade from its clicked state to its normal state)

The only ways I can think of doing this is having a second fading sprite on top, which seems like a sloppy method, and you can also animate the color and animate the blending over the texture. In other words, you can just make the button flash a color. This isn't exactly what I need but its the same concept, just with textures!

Any ideas? Also, any tips on making nice looking buttons in spritekit/iOS?

Comment: You basically already detailed the two possible solutions (two textures changing their alpha properties, or color & colorBlendFactor changes). I have nothing else to add to that. ;)

Comment: Alright :) although, is there a cleaner way to do this without just adding a second sprite as a child?

Comment: Nope, that's the way to do it.